# Why does perl complain about "Too many arguments for open" when I run it in a shell script?

Tags: perl

I run my Perl script (*gettotal.pl*) and it works fine. I managed to get the sum of TOTAL.txt and append the output value to test.txt. But when I run it inside shell script (*test.sh*) I got this error:

> Too many arguments for open at /home/daily/scripts/per_NODE_HR/gettotal.pl line 29, near ""$dir")"
>   Execution of /home/daily/scripts/per_NODE_HR/gettotal.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

What is the difference between running it manually (./gettotal.pl) and running it inside shell script? Simple yet still confusing for me:-)

*gettotal.pl*

```
#!/opt/perl/bin/perl-w

use strict;

my $sum;

open(FH,"/home/daily/scripts/per_NODE_HR/date.txt");
chomp (my @date = <FH>);

my $path = "/home/daily/output/per_NODE_HR/$date[0]/TOTAL.txt";
open(FILE,"$path") or die "Unable to open $path: $!";
my @hits = <FILE>;

$sum=sum($#hits);
print "TOTAL =  $sum";

print "\n";
sub sum {
if ($_[0] == 0) {
return $hits[0];
}
return $hits[$_[0]] + sum($_[0]-1);
}
my $dir = "/home/daily/output/per_NODE_HR/$date[0]/test.txt";
open(OUT,'>>', "$dir") or die "Cannot open $dir: $!";
print OUT "TOTAL: $sum";

close OUT;
close FILE;
close FH;
```

shell script

```
#!/bin/sh

perl /home/daily/scripts/per_NODE_HR/gettotal.pl
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you're getting suggests that your system perl is a truly ancient version...  The three-argument form of `open` was added in perl 5.6.0 (released March 22, 2000), so a complaint about your `open` having too many arguments would seem to indicate that you're passing your code to a 5.5.x or older perl.  Try `perl -v` on the command line to see what version the system perl is.

As for how to resolve this, call it in your shell script with just `/home/daily/scripts/per_NODE_HR/gettotal.pl` instead of `perl /home/daily/scripts/per_NODE_HR/gettotal.pl` and it will get passed to `/opt/perl/bin/perl-w` as specified in the shebang (`#!`) line, just like it does when you run it manually with `./gettotal.pl`.

Incidentally, you might also want to add a `use warnings` along with `use strict` instead of relying on your code being run with `perl -w`.  If you use `perl gettotal.pl`, warnings will not be enabled.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly, `perl` != `/opt/perl/bin/perl`.

Try `which perl`.