# opening file in perl gives errors?

Tags: perl, file-io

I am writing a perl script which reads a text file (which contains absolute paths of many files one below the other), calculates the file names from abs path & then appends all file names separated by a space to the same file. So, consider a test.txt file:

```
D:\work\project\temp.txt
D:\work/tests/test.abc
C:/office/work/files.xyz
```

So after running the script the same file will contain:

```
D:\work\project\temp.txt
D:\work/tests/test.abc
C:/office/work/files.xyz

temp.txt test.abc files.xyz
```

I have this script revert.pl:

```
use strict;

foreach my $arg (@ARGV)
{
    open my $file_handle, '>>', $arg or die "\nError trying to open the file $arg : $!";
    print "Opened File : $arg\n";
    my @lines = <$file_handle>;
    my $all_names = "";

    foreach my $line (@lines)
    {
        my @paths = split(/\\|\//, $line);
        my $last = @paths;
        $last = $last - 1;
        my $name = $paths[$last];
        $all_names = "$all_names $name";
    }

    print $file_handle "\n\n$all_names";
    close $file_handle;
}
```

When I run the script I am getting the following error:

```
>> perl ..\revert.pl .\test.txt
Too many arguments for open at ..\revert.pl line 5, near "$arg or"
Execution of ..\revert.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What is wrong over here?

**UPDATE:** The problem is that we are using a very old version of perl. So changed the code to:

```
use strict;

for my $arg (@ARGV)
{
print "$arg\n";
open (FH, ">>$arg") or die "\nError trying to open the file $arg : $!";
print "Opened File : $arg\n";
my $all_names = "";
my $line = "";

for $line (<FH>)
{
    print "$line\n";
    my @paths = split(/\\|\//, $line);
    my $last = @paths;
    $last = $last - 1;
    my $name = $paths[$last];
    $all_names = "$all_names $name";
}
print "$line\n";

if ($all_names == "")
{
    print "Could not detect any file name.\n";
}
else
{
    print FH "\n\n$all_names";
    print "Success!\n";
}
close FH;
}
```

Now its printing the following:

```
>> perl ..\revert.pl .\test.txt
.\test.txt
Opened File : .\test.txt

Could not detect any file name.
```

What could be wrong now?

Comment: are you sure you are running that script? the open sentence is fine, try to print $arg before open.

Comment: Hi @MiguelPrz since the script is giving compile error, its not running, hence its not printing the arg also.

Comment: if I comment the open line then the value of $arg is printed as: **.\test.txt**

Comment: Ii runs perfectly on a newer version of perl .
Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146023/why-does-perl-complain-about-too-many-arguments-for-open-when-i-run-it-in-a-sh

Comment: @Raju yes Thank You so much!
We have a very old version of perl here.
Made the changes.
Thanks again :)

Comment: What version of Perl? (`perl -v`)

Comment: 5.005_3 i.e. built in 1999, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are running an old perl version, so you have to use the 2 params open version:

```
open(File_handle, ">>$arg") or die "\nError trying to open the file $arg : $!";
```

note I wrote `File_handle` without the `$`. Also, read and writting operations to the file will be:

```
@lines = <File_handle>;
#...
print File_handle "\n\n$all_names";
#...
close File_handle;
```

Update: reading file lines:

```
open FH, "+>>$arg" or die "open file error: $!";
#...
while( $line = <FH> ) {
   #...
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question.
Now its opening the file but cannot read the lines.
Now there should not be any problem with older version as I have used the syntax compliant with older version of perl, as per this: http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/11/begperl2.html

Comment: Apparently it is able to read the lines only if opened by read mode & not by write mode. Neither overwrite not append mode is able to read the lines.
Maybe the perl version is just too old.
Thanks for all your help.
Will get back to you if there are any problems in writing to file.

Comment: try this: open FH, "+>>$arg";

Comment: Its opening but in read mode because its not printing anything to file.

Comment: Anyways I am again opening the file in write mode & then writing, so problem solved.
Thank YOU a lot for your kind help. :)
If you find some time please try to answer my question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207860/determine-version-of-microsoft-windows-using-c-shell-script